# Failed to list lazy routes: Unknown module './src/app/app.module#AppModule'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Afte upgrading to Angular 9 (from Angular 8) and running `ng build` I am getting

```
ERROR in Failed to list lazy routes: Unknown module './src/app/app.module#AppModule'.
```

It seems that the main app module cannot be found.

This is my **main.ts** file:

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I have created a new project and was able to run it successfully.

This means that there changed something from 8 to 9.

Any ideas what I have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like similar issue was being reported [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32547)

> Possible solution is to set `aot: true` in angular.json

P.S
See the `angular.json` difference between [CLI v8 and CLI v9](https://github.com/cexbrayat/angular-cli-diff/compare/8.3.25...9.0.2#files_bucket)

> [Migration tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60143118/415078) :
>
> - npm install @angular/cli -g
> - ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

Comment: It was indeed a combination of different things. The angular.json and the package.json had to be updated in my case to make everything work again.

Answer (score 4):

For lazy loaded modules via the router, make sure you are using [dynamic imports](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#loadchildren-string-syntax). Importing via string is removed in v9. ng update should take care of this automatically. Learn more on angular.io.

---

In your `app-routing.module.ts` you shoud be have something like that:

```
{
        path: '/',
        loadChildren: () => import('src/app/app.module').then(m => m.AppModule)
}
```

Comment: `dynamic imports` is not v9 feature, it is there since v8. If that was a case he should get a compilation error but this one is run-time error. Also if you do upgrade like `ng update @angular/core` the schematics taking care of `dynamic imports`migration automatically.