# Upgrade to Angular9 , Node module is not detecting in component spec

Tags: angular9

My spec file is not detecting Node modules after Angular 9 upgrade

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141743/build-errors-after-upgrading-from-angular-8-to-9

Comment: Please see link for error, this is happening only in spec files